# Why not working jquery show() function in wordpress?

Tags: jquery

I try create a quick comment form on my wordpress with a link like this:
[image]

My plan is when you click this link,you get a comment form with jquery show() function, where you can add a comment in ajax.
jquery:

```
 $.noConflict();
 jQuery( ".comment-mezo" ).click(function() {
 jQuery( "#comment-mezo" ).show( "slow" );
});
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="comment-mezo">Quick comment</a>
<div id="comment-mezo" style="display: none">
  <textarea id="comment"></textarea><br>
   <input type="submit">
</div>
```

This function work outside wordpress(i tryed it on jsbin), but inside not.
Why?
We know this thanks for Rares P and sri.:
The jquery is loaded and working.
The id change not help.
The show.js is loaded when the paged is loaded.
And we  use this for the script load:

```
<?php
   function show() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/show.js', array() );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'show' );?>
```

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. The limited subset of **WordPress**-specific jQuery issues has been adequately covered in existing WPSE questions and answers. Please search the site to find one that addresses your issue.

Comment: This very wordpress specifick,becouse this  function work on jsbin but on wordpress not.
I'm searched it the solution everywhere not jut here,but I not found,becouse I gess no exists solution for this.

Comment: You cannot use the same `id` multiple times in one document, this is invalid HTML and it breaks JavaScript. Not WordPress specific, sorry.

Comment: I chanced the id,but this not solve my problem,so this is a wordpress problem.
You can change the id-s to something else,but this not go work.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress runs `$.noConflict();` by default.

You attempting to run it again manually likely throws a

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'noConflict' of undefined

Make use of your browser's JS console rather than jsbin...

Comment: I'm not see this error on my website.

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Try to see if your js is loaded. Try this by adding: alert("test"); and refresh the website. If the "test" message doesn't appear it means that the js is not loaded.

Here's the best way to load js: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

**2**. If js is loaded, I guess you have some errors

Download Firebug addon for your browser. Activate it, browse your website, right click somewhere on the website and select "Inspect this element with Firebug". You will see a window appearing on the footer of your website. Select the "Console" window, and there you'll see if there's any Javascript / jQuerry error.

Comment: Like this:?

$.noConflict();
 jQuery( ".comment-mezo" ).click(function() {
 jQuery( "#comment-mezo" ).show( "slow" );
});
function display_alert()
  {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  }

Comment: add alert("test"); to be the first line of your js file. If works, add it to be the first line after jQuery( ".comment-mezo" ).click(function() { - to see if it identifies the click action

Comment: I tryed this:
add alert("test"); 
$.noConflict();
jQuery( ".comment-mezo" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "#comment-mezo" ).show( "slow" );
});
But nothing happening, I click on the link,and not load on:D
Briliant -.-" :D

Comment: it means that the javascript file is not loaded. You should go to the header.php file from your theme and load the javascript file from there. In the message above you can see the best way to load a js file.

Comment: Yes, i put this on header,after the jquery:
<?php
function show() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/show.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'show' );?>
And  thats sure run this script, i put the js file on my theme directory and my root directory

Comment: Right click on your website and select the option to view the page source. Does your js file appears there? If no, it means that the js it's not loaded.

Comment: I gess this is a problem:
'show.js?ver=1'
My js file name is show.js, I don't know why add the wordpress the version to my script, i'm not ask for him :D

Comment: it;s not a problem, wordpress does this by default, if you don't enter the version when you're using wp_enqueue_script, it will set if 1 by default

Comment: but please click on the line that loads the js file, it should open the js file if the path is good, if not, that that's the problem!

Comment: The js file is load correctly,but the function,still not work

Comment: in this case, please check if the html is good, check if the class really exists and is unique. You have lots of comments with the same class. You should add an id after the id="comment-mezo", the id should be "comment-mezo-1"..."comment-mezo-10" so it will open the comment form for the post you want it to open.

Comment: I changed the <a class="comment-mezo">to <a class="comment-mezo-mutat"> but still not working

Comment: You said that the alert("test"); doesn't worked. That means that the js file haven't loaded. Replace everything from your js file with only: alert("test"); the only problem I can see is that the js file is not loaded.

Comment: Yeah,now I see the alaert:D

Comment: ok, the problem is your jquery code

Comment: You should use something like this: $( ".comment-mezo" ).click(function() {
$( "#comment-mezo" ).show( "slow" );
});

Comment: I try it,but this not load.
You can play with this in here:
http://www.neocsatblog.mblx.hu/#

Comment: Take a look again at your page source code and make sure that your js file is loaded after jquery! This must be the problem..

Comment: My first script the jquery,you can see on line 18:
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/plugins/lightview/jquery.js"></script>
the show.js is 242 line:
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.neocsatblog.mblx.hu/wp-content/themes/ifeature/show.js?ver=3.6.1'></script>

Comment: replace your js content with this: $(function() {
 $( ".comment-mezo-mutat" ).click(function() { 
     alert("test");
  $( "#comment-mezo2" ).show( "slow" ); 
 })
});

Comment: when you'll click the comment button it should display the "test" message. The function I used is equivalent with "document ready", more exactly it will load the content after the page will load

Comment: I edited,butwhen you click the link,still nothing happen

Comment: replace everything with this code (and tell me the answer): if (window.jQuery) {  
    alert("jquery is loaded");  
} else {
    alert("jquery is NOT loaded");
}

Comment: Please do not use comments for excessive discussion, they aren't meant for that. Update question or answer with additional details as appropriate.

Comment: The alert is visible,when the page loaded.

Comment: but what's the answer of the alert, is the jquery loaded or not? that's the question.

Comment: Jquery Is loaded

Comment: Have you other idea?:D

Comment: The @sri sayed me the problem is the with id-s.
The link render in php,so this id-s everywhere where you can see the quick komment link

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be because of the use of same id for all the div elements. Try giving unique id for every div element that follows the Quick Comment link.

Comment: I changed the <a class="comment-mezo">to <a class="comment-mezo-mutat"> but still not working

Comment: I didn't mean the anchor tag. I meant for the div element that follows. Use ids something like comment-mezo1, comment-mezo2 etc... Ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Oh okey i understand you.
I chanched the div id to: id="comment-mezo2" but still not work

Comment: Please, if you could, share your code on jsfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: Here the code,you can play it:D
http://jsbin.com/emuziBu/2/edit
I don't know why,but here working with old id-s

Comment: Now, please check the code now and let me know if that is what you desire and i can update my Answer accordingly.

Comment: How do you mean?
I just saw the old code.
Can you wish that change the id-s?

Comment: Please check this http://jsbin.com/emuziBu/5/edit

Comment: That's very piss me off...
This not loaded.

Comment: I mean that's not you erorr,that's wordpress

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what you are saying. Please do not use foul language, I am genuinely trying to help you and possibly others.

Comment: Your right, sorry,but I'm just a little angry for this.
How can this possible?
Outside work but in wordpress not?

Comment: It is not Wordpress problem. As i understand, you have multiple blog posts on a single page and you would want to add comments. So you should develop a logic that gives unique ids for each blog post(just like i showed you). Only then you can achieve what you want. If you check your website, my guess is, you are having the same id used more than once. If it is true, that is the problem and nothing else. Please remember IDs must be unique for JavaScript to work properly.

Comment: But this not possible,every blog post (with quick comment link and div) come in php.
I can't change the id.
Otherwise,this html tags place on function.php.
You think this the problem?

Comment: You should figure out a way else you may not have a solution. Sorry, i cannot help further without being able to look at your website code.

Comment: Just tell me what do you like and I give it for you.

Comment: "*But this not possible,every blog post (with quick comment link and div) come in php. I can't change the id.*" WordPress does not define HTML container IDs in the Template. The **Theme** does that. Edit your Theme such that each targeted container has a unique ID.

Comment: This not solve my problem,becouse the link comes with meta datas,like this:
http://pastebin.com/mq0t8jcg
You see?
You can change the ids,but next time,there is the problem,there id-s left everywhere